# why are platform.platform and sysconfig.get_platform showing different OS versions on macOS?

Tags: python, macos

System:

```
Mac OS 12.5
2019 Intel MBP 16"
python 3.9.13 from python.org
```

See below that the different modules seem to report different versions of macOS. Why is that?

```
> python
Python 3.9.13 (v3.9.13:6de2ca5339, May 17 2022, 11:23:25) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit'
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_platform()
'macosx-10.9-x86_64'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

They're implemented for different purposes:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.platform

> ###### `platform.platform(aliased=0, terse=0)`
>
> Returns a single string identifying the underlying platform with as much useful information as possible.
>
> The output is intended to be *human readable* rather than machine parseable. It may look different on different platforms and this is intended.
>
> ...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_platform

> ###### `sysconfig.get_platform()`
>
> Return a string that identifies the current platform.
>
> This is used mainly to distinguish platform-specific build directories and platform-specific built distributions. Typically includes the OS name and version and the architecture (as supplied by `os.uname()`), although the exact information included depends on the OS; e.g., on Linux, the kernel version isn’t particularly important.
>
> ...

Comment: I suppose I can appreciate that, but what about the different purposes require them to report different operating system versions (i.e. 10.9 v 10.16)?  I suppose its also worth questioning why platform.platform is reporting 10.16, which I believe refers to Mac OS11, while the machine is actually Mac OS12.

Comment: @VinceW. I didn't even notice that. Seems like it's just flat wrong.

Comment: It does seem to be flat wrong.  I just compiled 3.10.6 from source and I get the right answer so it is something to do with the distributed binaries.  I get the same wrong answers from conda/python.org/homebrew provided pre-built binaries.  When compiling from source, platform.platform() reports: `'macOS-12.5-x86_64-i386-64bit'`